# how can i divide an image into block and get the id of the block that is clicked by mouse using java script

Tags: javascript

Imagine I wish to divide an on-screen image into rectangular tiles and each tile should have a unique identifier.  When a user clicks on a tile, I wish to know which tile was clicked. I tried to split the image into tiles with JavaScript, but I cannot uniquely identify a particular tile by using mouse click.

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a coding service. If you need help, please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried so far so we can help you. I'd recommend you to go take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or the [Help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Changed for readability and comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Add `click` event listeners to all `imgs` and then use `this` to get details of clicked image.

```js
const length = 5;
const container = document.querySelector('div#container');

for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.id = "img" + i;
    img.src = "picture.jpg"; // Image url
    container.append(img);
}

const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');

imgs.forEach((img) => {
    img.addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log(this.id);
    });
});
```

```css
img {
    height: 200px;
    widows: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```